# What is that Linux command that gives you a tight little system summary that includes an ASCII icon image of your OS right in the terminal?

Tags: command-line

What is that Linux command that gives you a tight little info summary, such as OS, CPU, RAM, temp., etc, and also includes an ASCII icon image of your OS right in the terminal?

I've used it before, but now I can't remember it for the life of me.

Anyone? Bueller?

Comment: It's not just Linux. It's available for most Unixen. For example you can install it and run it on Mac OS to boast about your new M2 Macbook.

Comment: `linuxlogo` from the same name package; won’t weite a full answer rn as I’m on mobile

Answer (score 42):

You're most probably looking for [`neofetch`](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch). To install it, first update your package repositories:

```
sudo apt update
```

and then run:

```
sudo apt install neofetch
```

After that you can run:

```
neofetch
```

to get the summary you want, which should be similar to the following (I'm on a Fedora machine right now, but that doesn't really make any difference):

[image: neofetch screenshot]

For more options see [`man neofetch`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/neofetch.1.html).

Comment: Why is it called neofetch? Because it makes your screenshots really fetch?

Comment: @user253751: The author explicitly refers to and compares with `screenfetch`, so I would assume they named it `neofetch` because it is a more modern version of `screenfetch`.

Comment: @user253751: One of the first hits on Google for "screenfetch" is the GitHub repository and the first section on that page is the "About" section which says "Fetches system/theme information in terminal for Linux desktop screenshots."

Comment: @user253751 - Quit trying to make fetch happen. It's not gonna happen :)

Comment: I was just poking around on the neofetch github site and realized there's been no activity in months. Someone has forked it and has been busy updating it. I just tried [hyfetch](https://github.com/hykilpikonna/hyfetch) and it's every bit as nice.

Answer (score 7):

One good alternative to `neofetch` is [screenfetch](https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch.git).

You can clone the github repo, get it from the existing Ubuntu repos, or add the [screenfetch ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Edjcj/+archive/ubuntu/screenfetch).

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install screenfetch
```

Configuration instructions are on the github page.

Comment: Can you please explain why you suggest this alternative?

Comment: @A.L I suggested this alternative because it seemed to me to be the best alternative and I believe choice is better than no choice. On the rare occasion that I use one of these things, I use neofetch, but there's a minor aesthetic difference and a simplicity to the other than some might prefer.

Answer (score 4):

There is another excellent choice: [HyFetch](https://github.com/Aleksanaa/hyfetch) which is an update and fork of the *older* neofetch. This produces the ascii image and most of the system details that you require:

[image]

Importantly the developer has also given an opportunity for those in the LGBTQ+ community to express themselves with colour, and those that support them *the same opportunity*:

[image]

My images are drawn from my Slackware setup but HyFetch can be installed easily enough (with my old friend pipx) on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install pip python3.10-venv
python3 -m pip install --user pipx
python3 -m pipx ensurepath
source ~/.profile 
pipx install hyfetch
```

Tested on Jammy Jellyfish and it all ran very, very smoothly...

Comment: Excellent suggestion - I'll definitely be checking out HyFetch as a Neofetch replacement.. 

Answer (score 1):

My goto for this sort of thing is `inxi`:

```
$ inxi
CPU: quad core 11th Gen Intel Core i7-1165G7 (-MT MCP-)
speed/min/max: 2598/400/4700 MHz Kernel: 5.19.2-arch1-1 x86_64 Up: 2d 5h 33m
Mem: 9599.6/31799.3 MiB (30.2%) Storage: 953.87 GiB (27.9% used) Procs: 377
Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.20
```

No ASCII art but loads of useful options. `-F` for "full", for example:

```
$ inxi -F
System:
  Host: oregano Kernel: 5.19.2-arch1-1 arch: x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: Cinnamon v: 5.4.9 Distro: Arch Linux
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20VX000FUK v: ThinkPad P14s Gen 2i
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: LENOVO model: 20VX000FUK v: SDK0J40697 WIN
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: LENOVO v: N34ET51W (1.51 )
    date: 06/10/2022
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 42.2 Wh (79.6%) condition: 53.0/51.0 Wh (104.0%)
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i7-1165G7 bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    cache: L2: 5 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1895 min/max: 400/4700 cores: 1: 908 2: 2800 3: 2800
    4: 2800 5: 902 6: 1008 7: 2800 8: 1143
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: NVIDIA TU117GLM [Quadro T500 Mobile] driver: nvidia
    v: 515.65.01
  Device-3: Chicony Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.4 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.3 driver: X:
    loaded: intel unloaded: modesetting gpu: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 14.0.6 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 22.1.6
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.2-arch1-1 running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.56 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I219-V driver: e1000e
  IF: enp0s31f6 state: down mac: 84:a9:38:e4:c1:e0
  Device-2: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz driver: iwlwifi
  IF: wlp9s0 state: up mac: 70:cd:0d:57:0a:6c
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB used: 265.68 GiB (27.9%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVLB1T0HBLR-000L7
    size: 953.87 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 55.38 GiB used: 40.82 GiB (73.7%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p5
  ID-2: /home size: 668.36 GiB used: 224.75 GiB (33.6%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/dm-0
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 29.95 GiB used: 110.8 MiB (0.4%)
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p7
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 61.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 65535 fan-1: 2863 fan-2:
Info:
  Processes: 381 Uptime: 2d 5h 34m Memory: 31.05 GiB used: 9.43 GiB (30.4%)
  Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.20
```

You can install it on Ubuntu with `sudo apt install inxi`.

Comment: I really like `inxi` but I don't think it is an answer to this question.