# How to get the machine specs from the terminal?I

Tags: cpu, gpu

Is there a quick way to get the machine specs from the terminal? (GPU model, memory, CPU model, memory etc).
I am getting the info bit by bit by different commands such as lscpu and lspci but cant get the complete picture

EDIT:No it does not answer my question since many of the answers are not from the terminal.

Comment: Please download and run the [Ubuntu Forum's system-info script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info/); If you need [more] help: let it upload the result to a pastebin. Then edit your original question to show a link to the pastebin. That information will help me and others understand what you have (software and hardware) and it will help us help you.

Comment: Depending on the level of detail: [Neofetch will give you basic information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1424845/what-is-that-linux-command-that-gives-you-a-tight-little-system-summary-that-inc/).

Comment: `lshw` will show all of that. If that output is too much, then `inxi`,`neofetch` or `screenfetch` can show more condensed information

Comment: lshw and inxi are small command line tools, that you run from the terminal. The Ubuntu Forum's system-info script must be downloaded, but once there, it is also a command line tool, to be run from the terminal. It provides a more complete picture, also useful for debugging. If you want a tool that is already there in Ubuntu, you can run the command line `sudo lshw | less` to scroll easily through the output from lshw.

Answer (score 1):

Install neofetch from your package manager and run it in the terminal.